# How can write this code which execute only one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to write this code which execute only one query instead of two and fire validations also ? update_all bypasses all validations defined in model.

```
model = ModelName.find(params[:id])
success = model.update_attribute(:column_name, nil)
```

Comment: I think you may need to clarify your question, also post more code and say what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

You can not. Running the validations does include at least one step: Loading the database record into a ruby object (which takes one query). Updating the database of course takes another query. So in any case, you will have two queries for your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update` method:

```
# Updates one record
  User.update(1, :name => 'testtesttest')
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update

but it's still two queries as @mosch said.

```
  User Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "name" = 'testtesttest', "updated_at" = '2011-05-03 11:41:23.000000' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```